# How to pass data from a TableVIew to ViewController when I click a cell of table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working on an IOS project.

what i want to do is that when I click a label of ViewController, 
the segue takes me to the tableview so that I can choose one of the cells. 
and When I click one of the cells, it goes back to ViewController by
**"[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]"** 
and the label shows the txt of clicked cell.

i am trying to do with NSUserDefault but it doesn't brink the data when it gets back to ViewController after click.

how can i solve this? any idea?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You're going to need to post your code if want help getting your NSUserDefaults to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways you can do this. One is something along these lines:

- Declare a property on the tableview controller to hold a reference to the view controller,e.g.

  ```
  @property(nonatomic,assign) MyViewController *original_controller;
  ```
- Set the reference when preparing for the segue from your view controller.

  ```
  MyTableViewController *tvc=(MyTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]; 
  tvc.original_controller=self;
  ```
- Use the reference to set the label when responding to the tableview cell selection.

  ```
  original_controller.myLabel.text=<selected text>
  ```

Hope this helps.